# Advanced search form shows more tables for more results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, html-table, show

I'm following Advanced search form episode from Railscasts.

This is the search model:

```
 search.rb
 class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :keywords

    def segnalazione_animalis
    @segnalazione_animalis ||= find_segnalazione_animalis
    end

   private
   def find_segnalazione_animalis
   segnalazione_animalis = SegnalazioneAnimali.order(:Titolo)
   segnalazione_animalis = segnalazione_animalis.where("Titolo like ?", "%#
                     {keywords}%") if keywords.present?
   segnalazione_animalis = segnalazione_animalis.where("Titolo like ?", "%# 
                                        {keywords}%") if keywords.present?
   segnalazione_animalis = segnalazione_animalis.where("classe like ?", "%#
                                        {keywords1}%") if keywords1.present?
   segnalazione_animalis = segnalazione_animalis.where("specie like ?", "%#
                                        {keywords2}%") if keywords2.present?
   segnalazione_animalis
   end
   end
```

I have a searches_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
def new
   @search = Search.new
end
def create
   @search = Search.create!(params[:search])
   redirect_to @search
end
def show
@search = Search.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

The new.html.erb file is

```
   <%= form_for @search do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :keywords %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :keywords1,"Classe" %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :keywords1 %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :keywords2,"Specie" %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :keywords2 %>
   </div>

    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
   <% end %>
```

And the show file:

```
   <h1>Search Results</h1>
   <%= render @search.segnalazione_animalis %>
```

I take the partial rendered from the index file of my segnalazione_animalis folder:

```
   _segnalazione_animali.html.erb
        <table class="table1">
        <tr>
        <th>Titolo:</th><br>
        <th>Classe:</th>
        <th>Creato il:</th>
        <th>Ultima Modifica il:</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>

        <% @search.segnalazione_animalis.each do |segnalazione_animali| %>

        <tr>
        <td><%= segnalazione_animali.Titolo  %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><%= segnalazione_animali.classe %>
        <td><%= l(segnalazione_animali.created_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")</td>
        <td><%= l(segnalazione_animali.updated_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")%>                 
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Mostra', [segnalazione_animali.user, segnalazione_animali] 
                           %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
```

When the search works and there is more than one result it shows more tables with every result.
Example: it find two results, it shows two tables with the two results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, you display the results using a partial and the partial defines a new table so if there are multiple animals there will be multiple tables.  When you render a collection rails will automatically render the corresponding partial for EACH object.

If you want only one table, then do this in the show file

```
  <h1>Search Results</h1>
        <table class="table1">
        <tr>
        <th>Titolo:</th><br>
        <th>Classe:</th>
        <th>Creato il:</th>
        <th>Ultima Modifica il:</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
   <%= render @search.segnalazione_animalis %>
    </table>
```

And in the partial just include the

```
<tr>
  <td><%= segnalazione_animali.Titolo  %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td><%= segnalazione_animali.classe %>
  <td><%= l(segnalazione_animali.created_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")</td>
  <td><%= l(segnalazione_animali.updated_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")%></td>
  td><%= link_to 'Mostra', [segnalazione_animali.user, segnalazione_animali] %></td>
</tr>
```

All part of the magic of rails. :)